# How to play only one specific video at a time in HTML page

Tags: html, jquery, html5-video

I am trying to play only one video object at a time.

**Problem:**
When I click on any other videos they also start playing, now multiple videos are playing together.

**Expected result:** 
I want only one video to play at a time. The one that a user has clicked *Play* on should play, and also automatically make any other playing video object to go into a "pause" mode.

My example code is:

```
<video  
        id="mainvideo" name="files" preload="metadata" controls loop
        controlslist="nodownload noremoteplayback noplaybracket"  
        sun="<?php echo $row['pro_id']; ?>"
        value="playing" > 

<source id="mp4Source" type="video/mp4" src="<?php echo $row['files']; ?>" > 
</video>
```

Can anyone guide me how I should write the code for getting the same expected result?

Comment: There seems to be only code for one video in your question? It's also not just HTML, there's PHP code in there as well. That being said, what research have you done? Have you seen the [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) and [<video>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)? There's a lot of documentation out there. What have you tried? See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Deleting a closed question and reposting it isn't helpful.